# Getting a form element to enter only at 11 characters

Tags: javascript

Right now i have it to tab on enter but i would like to get it to ONLY enter the element when there is 11 characters.  How would i do it?

```
function getNextElement(field) {
    var form = field.form;
    for ( var e = 0; e < form.elements.length; e++) {
        if (field == form.elements[e]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return form.elements[++e % form.elements.length];
}

function tabOnEnter(field, evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
        if (evt.preventDefault) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        } else if (evt.stopPropagation) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            evt.returnValue = false;
        }
        getNextElement(field).focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just something simple like that:

```
if(field.value.length === 11)
   getNextElement(field).focus();
```

Comment: that works perfect but i can't even backspace the highlighted text to put something else in.  It just constantly auto tabs.  I need to be able to over-write the text at least but the tab works fine.

Comment: @chrisbahr as I understood this code shoud be invoked only when you press Enter button, so I can't understand yet why it autotabs

Comment: @zavg sorry I stand corrected. He is in fact handling what keys he wants.

Comment: it's all going to be done with a scanner so i need it to keep tabbing through the fields after each scan with the last being submit.  i just need to be able to scan my key that i use to focus the first field to start over instead of the scanner tabbing down to submit again. so in a nut shell, i need it all to work normally but not to tab when "1" character is entered.  I suppose if there was a range i could put in and have tab to enter to not function with only 1 character in the field?